# Access $route inside directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is any way how to access `$route` inside directive function?

What I basically want is to know the current `templateUrl`, say:

```
app.directive("scrollable", function ($document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $document.bind('scroll', function (evt) {
                 console.log($route.current.templateUrl); // $route is undefined!
            });
        }
    };
});
```

P.S. I am newbie in the AngularJS, don't be so rigorous :)

Comment: Have you tried passing it to the directive?

Comment: What router are you using? Default or ui-router?

Comment: Have you tried to inject it like `app.directive("scrollable", ['$document', '$route', function ($document, $route) {...}]);`

Comment: Why "-1" guys? So pity...

Comment: @MikeFeltman No, I did not try. I am newbie in the angular js

Comment: @Andremoniy had to make it an answer instead of comment :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to inject the `$route` to the directive

```
app.directive("scrollable", function ($document,$route) {
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. I will accept your answers in 10 minutes :)